# Read out nested JSONObject with Java. Don't get the inner JSONObject

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a JSONObject from within another JSONObject. The first output works, the second, i.e. the JSONObject within, does not. Here I get the following error

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Values"] not found.

This is the output of the first object / array

> ergebnis: {"Description":"","Objects":[{"RefStr":"76-1044-0","ClassName":"Application","Values":{"providerorg-refstr":"262-462-0",...}]}

This is how I try to get the data:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(ergebnis);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
JSONObject inside = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Values");
System.out.println(inside);
```

Comment: Which json library are you using and what is `ergebnis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values object is present in Objects. This objects is an array. You can try like below,

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
 System.out.println(jsonObject);
 JSONObject jsonObject1= jsonObject.getJSONObject("ergebnis");
 System.out.println(jsonObject1);
 JSONArray objects = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("Objects");
 System.out.println(objects);
 JSONObject inside = objects.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("Values");
 System.out.println(inside);
```